# Where To Get Some Resources To Learn HyperTalk?

Tags: resources, hypertalk

I'm now emulating a Macintosh IIci(System 7.5.5 68k) and now I want to learn HyperTalk(HyperCard), but I don't know where to start, then if someone can help me I will be very happy! **:D**

Comment: I take it you've already searched for HyperTalk tutorials using your search engine of choice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HyperTalk is the embedded scripting language for Apple's HyperCard application. Most of the commands control HyperCard and you will have to understand that application to make use of HyperTalk. Probably the best HyperCard book ever written is Danny Goodman's [The Complete HyperCard Handbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0966551427).

If you are just interested in controlling old Macs with scripting, investigate [AppleScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AppleScript). This was supported on 68K Macs running System 7.

Answer (score 2):

I've put up a few things that might be useful at http://hypercard.org

- At the top of the page is a little tutorial movie that shows how one would create a simple HyperCard stack that flips between cards and covers the basics of using HyperCard
- In the mirror of the Pantechnicon, under http://hypercard.org/Pantechnicon/Stacks/Education/HyperCard/ there is an archive of the HyperTalk QuickRef (as HT_QuickRef.sit), a handy little reference stack that describes all the HyperTalk commands in a short, concise way. Once you know the basics of HyperTalk, this can go a long way to help you find a command that does what you want to do. That folder also contains some other stacks like "HyperCard Basics" that might be of use to you.
- Try to find as many HyperCard stacks as you can find and examine them. You can go into pretty much every HyperCard stack, choose the button or field tool, select a button or field that does something interesting, choose the "Button Info..." resp. "Field Info..." menu item and examine its properties and its script to see what makes it tick. You can also use "Card Info...", "Bkgnd Info..." and "Stack Info..." to see scripts and properties of those objects (you can't really select a card, after all). You can also go through the stacks that come with HyperCard, which are chock-full of fun buttons and text fields that you can copy and paste into your own stacks and use there as is or modify slightly to fit your needs.

If you can fibd a stack named 101 Scripts and Buttons somewhere, that also demonstrated some neat techniques.